# Using flutter flutter_image_compress to upload base64 compressed file but cant uncompress in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flutter, dart

I can successfully upload a file to s3 by

1. using  flutter_image_compress to compress and
2. converting the file to base64.

Now I can decode the file:

```
 base64_string = open("img1b95b3ed9e494595b01610f06d9f074b.txt", "r").readlines()[0]
```

Now after that all fails:

```
 msg = base64.b64decode(base64_string)
 inflated = zlib.decompress(msg)

inflated = zlib.decompress(msg)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

So what is the proper method to decode in python from using the flutter flutter_image_compress package?

Thanks

PS this is now I compress in flutter:

```
Future<Uint8List?> testCompressFile(File file) async {
  var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(file.absolute.path,
      quality: 100,
      keepExif: true
      );
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

decoding base64 would give you `uint8List` which in python's terms would be a `byteArray`. Please try converting that `byteArray` into `bytes` to gain the binary data. You don't need the `zlib`:

```py
listOfInt = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
byteArray = bytearray(listOfInt)
print(byteArray) # bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06')
byteObj = bytes(byteArray)
print(byteObj) # b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06'
```